# Image not rendering in listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app, I am using a `SFListView` to show images. It works for most of the images, but some in particular rarely ever render. And it's always the same ones. I checked the image urls in my browser and it shows the images as expected. This is the xaml for the image:

```
<Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AddCommand, Source = {x:Reference listView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>

    <Image.Source>
        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding ImageURL}" CacheValidity="1" CachingEnabled="true"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

I recently changed my xaml to bind directly to the `UriImageSource` so that I can take advantage of the caching, and I wasn't having this problem before this change, so I know it's not the URL that's the problem. It doesn't render particular images correctly now, any idea why? I am testing on an Android device.

Comment: Does those image that can not load start with HTTPS?

Comment: Yes it does, but so do my other images that load fine.

Comment: I solved it by doing `CachingEnabled="false"`, but now I don't have caching?